# Mongodb EHOSTUNREACH on Openshift Online 3 starter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, openshift-3

I was working on my Openshift app today and without changing anything related to mongodb connection I started getting this message:

```
/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.30.173.215:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)

npm info lifecycle bolao_2018@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs6/root/usr/bin/node" "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs6/root/usr/bin/npm" "run" "-d" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bolao_2018@0.1.0 start: `node main`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bolao_2018@0.1.0 start script 'node main'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bolao_2018 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node main
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bolao_2018
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bolao_2018
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/app-root/src/npm-debug.log
```

The one thing different was that I saw that for some reason the mongodb service tried and failed a new deploy so I ran one manually.

I also noticed that the IP addressit tries to connect is mongodb's cluster IP but the Node IP of the current running pod is different.

Can someone help me figure out what triggered the connection to break?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an IP address for the MongoDB in the client configuration that uses it, or a hostname. Technically the IP address of a ``Service`` shouldn't change, but usually always better to use the hostname for the ``Service``, which is the name of the ``Service`` object for the MongoDB instance.

Comment: I followed the steps on Openshift's docs, creating a environment variable MONGO_URL that contains: 'mongodb://admin:secret@<MongoDB-service-name>:27017/sampledb'. I'm not using a fixed IP in my code.

Comment: Not sure - but, if the mongodb image was patched with a security update, then the related OpenShift ImageStream resource may automatically schedule new Deployments (to distribute the updates throughout the cluster).  If there were ongoing issues with Deployments at the time, this may result in a scenario where the "mongodb service tried and failed a new deploy".

Manually issuing a new Deployment should restage the DB and resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately it didn't work. I tried redeploying mongo and my application and it still shows the same error

Comment: Which Online Starter cluster is this? The status page say us-east-1 is having some issues, it could be related to that. Have you looked at the MongoDB pod logs to verify it is not showing any errors when starting up? Have you tried using ``oc rsh`` to get into the MongoDB pod and use ``curl`` to see if MongoDB port can be accessed from the same pod?

Comment: Hey Graham!
So I ran `curl $MONGODB_SERVICE_HOST:$MONGODB_SERVICE_PORT` on my mongodb pod and got the same response I got running it on my application pod `Failed connect to 172.30.173.215:27017; No route to host`
My cluster is canada central

Comment: Use ``localhost:27017`` in the MongoDB pod. I want to verify it is working from inside.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, if you run ``oc describe pod`` for the MongoDB pod, what does the IP show as? Also what do you get for ``oc get endpoints mongodb``? Is the pod IP in that list? Also run ``oc describe service mongodb`` and verify same IPs listed there.

Comment: Presuming the service IP mapping might be screwed up somehow, try scaling down MongoDB to no replicas: ``oc scale --replicas=0 mongodb``. Then scale back up to 1 again.

Comment: So `curl localhost:27017` returns `It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.`

oc describe pod: IP 10.130.44.221

oc get endpoints mongodb
`NAME      ENDPOINTS             AGE
mongodb   10.130.44.221:27017   25d`

oc describe service mongodb:
`Name:                   mongodb
Type:                   ClusterIP
IP:                     172.30.173.215
Port:                   mongo   27017/TCP
Endpoints:              10.130.44.221:27017
Session Affinity:       None
Events:                 <none>`

Comment: scaling down and up didn't work. Same error log

Comment: any other ideas on how to figure this out? I even killed my whole project and started a new one without any luck

Answer (score 1):

From within a given `Project` scope, requests directed toward a hostname of "mongodb" should be routed to the Kubernetes `Service` named "mongodb" (when available).

To debug this connectivity issue:

1. Try opening a live terminal within your front-end container using the OpenShift web console. The front-end container must be within the same Project scope as the database service
2. Type `env` to list environment variables available to the front-end. If this container was started after the creation of the "mongodb" service, configuration strings should be visible the environment
3. Run `curl $MONGODB_SERVICE_HOST:$MONGODB_SERVICE_PORT` from the live terminal to verify the availability of the `mongodb` service

Comment: `Failed to connect to <same IP address and port of the mongo service> : no route to host` is the output of the `curl` command.